# Drawing on Canvas - PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR draws black! Why?

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, porter-duff

I'm trying to create a custom View which works simple: there is a Bitmap which is revealed by arc path - from 0deg to 360deg. Degrees are changing with some FPS.

So I made a custom View with overridden `onDraw()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    arcPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
    canvas.drawArc(arcRectF, -90, currentAngleSweep, true, arcPaint);
    arcPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, circleSourceRect, circleDestRect, arcPaint);
}
```

`arcPaint` is initialized as follows:

```
arcPaint = new Paint();
arcPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
arcPaint.setColor(Color.RED); // Color doesn't matter
```

Now, everything draws great, but... the background is BLACK in whole View.

If I set `canvas.drawColor(..., PorterDuff.Mode.DST)` and omit `canvas.drawBitmap()` - the arc is drawn properly on transparent background.

My question is - how to set `PorterDuff` modes to make it work with transparency?

Of course `bitmap` is 32-bit PNG with alpha channel.

Comment: have you found the solution? i am half of the way but when i am trying to save bitmap that gives me black part at remove area.

Comment: There's no solution for this without involving OpenGL or changing SDK. I finally decided non to draw bitmap at all.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` doesn't work with hardware acceleration. Just set

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Works perfectly for me.

Comment: `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);` In my case, this statement worked. But after setting this the lines and bitmaps are destroyed .

Comment: for me, just as @noobEinstien pointed out. `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);` works for any `PorterDuffXfermode` set to my paint. In my own particular scenario I am setting a linear gradient shader to my paint after applying a `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT`. `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` wipes the canvas completely transparent and then `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);` appears to be the default set with everything being faded into black instead of my view having a transparent fading edge.

Answer (score 19):

Use this statement during initialization of the view

```
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Comment: It solved the color change problem, but now my line got distoreted

Answer (score 3):

In [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) you can use `blendMode`:

```kotlin
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    drawIntoCanvas { it.saveLayer(Rect(Offset.Zero, size), Paint()) }
    drawRect(color = Color.Blue, size = size)
    
    val clearSize = Size(200.dp.toPx(), 300.dp.toPx())
    drawRect(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        topLeft = Offset((size.width - clearSize.width) / 2, (size.height - clearSize.height) / 2),
        size = clearSize,
        blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything is ok in your code except one thing: you get black background because your window is opaque. To achieve transparent result you should draw on another bitmap. In your onDraw method please a create new bitmap and do all the staff on it. After that draw this bitmap on your canvas.

For details and sample code please read [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947835/android-canvas-draw-transparent-circle-on-image/19963143#19963143):

Comment: Now imagine you create on each onDraw() a new Bitmap and draw on it. Sounds like killing the app. Finally its sad to say - but what I wanted to achieve is impossible! There was some tricks like setting View drawing on top of window (which made Canvas transparent) but I used View which overlapped another View so it doesn't fit.

Comment: @cadavre Impossible? Nitesh Tarani's answer worked for me

Comment: @cadavre Now i see that he answered 4 years later. You should mark his answer as the accepted one, tho

Answer (score 1):

to solve undesired `PorterDuff` effect
use the simplest method at first, like the OP's problem, a `Path.arcTo(*, *, *, *, false)` is enough -- note it's `arcTo`, not `addArc`, and the `false` means `no forceMoveTo` before adding arc -- there is no need for `PorterDuff`.

```
Path arcPath = new Path();
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    arcPath.rewind();
    arcPath.moveTo(arcRectF.centerX, arcRectF.centerY);
    arcPath.arcTo(arcRectF, -90, currentAngleSweep, false);
    arcPath.close();
    canvas.clipPath(arcPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, circleSourceRect, circleDestRect, arcPaint);
}
```

if you really need PorterDuff, mainly for complex color morphing, like blending gradients, don't draw color or shape or bitmap with PorterDuff filtering effect directly to the default canvas provided in `onDraw(Canvas)`, use some buffering/dest bitmap[s] with alpha channel--and `setHasAlpha(true)`-- to store the result from PorterDuff filtering, at last draw the bitmap to the default canvas without applying any filtering except matrix changing.
here's a working example to create border blurred round image:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
* Created by zdave on 6/22/17.
*/

public class BlurredCircleImageViewShader extends ImageView {
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Paint mPaint;
private Matrix matrix;
private static final float GRADIENT_RADIUS = 600f;  //any value you like, but should be big enough for better resolution.
private Shader gradientShader;
private Bitmap bitmapGradient;
private Bitmap bitmapDest;
private Canvas canvasDest;
public BlurredCircleImageViewShader(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public BlurredCircleImageViewShader(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public BlurredCircleImageViewShader(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    matrix = new Matrix();
    int[] colors = new int[]{Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK, Color.TRANSPARENT};
    float[] colorStops = new float[]{0f, 0.5f, 1f};
    gradientShader = new RadialGradient(GRADIENT_RADIUS, GRADIENT_RADIUS, GRADIENT_RADIUS, colors, colorStops, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    mPaint.setShader(gradientShader);

    bitmapGradient = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)(GRADIENT_RADIUS * 2), (int)(GRADIENT_RADIUS * 2), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmapDest = bitmapGradient.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapGradient);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, GRADIENT_RADIUS * 2, GRADIENT_RADIUS * 2, mPaint);

    canvasDest = new Canvas(bitmapDest);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    /*uncomment each of them to show the effect, the first and the third one worked, the second show the same problem as OP's*/
    //drawWithLayers(canvas);  //unrecommended.
    //drawWithBitmap(canvas);  //this shows transparent as black
    drawWithBitmapS(canvas);   //recommended.
}
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
private void drawWithLayers(Canvas canvas){
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    float width = canvas.getWidth();
    float hWidth = width / 2;
    //both saveLayerAlpha saveLayer worked here, and if without either of them,
    //the transparent area will be black.
    //int count = canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 255, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
    int count = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float scale = hWidth/GRADIENT_RADIUS;
    matrix.setTranslate(hWidth - GRADIENT_RADIUS, hWidth - GRADIENT_RADIUS);
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, hWidth, hWidth);
    gradientShader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, width, mPaint);

    canvas.restoreToCount(count);
}
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
private void drawWithBitmap(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float scale = canvas.getWidth() / (GRADIENT_RADIUS * 2);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapGradient, matrix, mPaint);  //transparent area is still black.
}
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
private void drawWithBitmapS(Canvas canvas){
    float scale = canvas.getWidth() / (GRADIENT_RADIUS * 2);
    int count = canvasDest.save();
    canvasDest.scale(1/scale, 1/scale); //tell super to draw in 1/scale.
    super.onDraw(canvasDest);
    canvasDest.restoreToCount(count);

    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvasDest.drawBitmap(bitmapGradient, 0, 0, mPaint);

    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);  //to scale bitmapDest to canvas.
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapDest, matrix, null);
    }
 }
```

some notes:
1, this view extends `ImageView` not `View`, there are some differences.
2, why `drawWithLayers` --`saveLayer` or `saveLayerAlpha`-- is unrecommended: a, they are uncertain, sometimes doesn't work right(show transparent as black), especially for `View` whoes `onDraw(Canvas)` is empty, while `ImageView.onDraw(Canvas)` used a `Drawable` to draw some; b, they are expensive, they allocate `off-screen bitmap` to store temporary drawing result, and there is no clear clues of any resource recycling mechanism.
3, using your own bitmap[s], is better for customized resource recycling.

Some people said, it's impossible to used PorterDuff without allocation bitmap[s] every drawing, because the bitmap's width, height can't be determined before drawing/layout/measure.
you CAN use buffering bitmap[s] for PorterDuff drawing: 
at first, allocate some big enough bitmap[s].
then, draw on the bitmap[s] with some matrix.
and the, draw the bitmap[s] into a dest bitmap with some matrix.
at last, draw the dest bitmap into canvas with some matrix.

some people recommend setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null), which is not an option for me, because it will cause onDraw(Canvas) to be called in a loop.

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks3uA.png)
  [source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8uK7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you have solid color background all you need to do is set Paint color to your background color. For example, if you have a white background you can do:

```
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

However, if you need to erase a line with a transparent background you try this:
In order to draw with a transparent color you must use Paint setXfermode which will only work if you set a bitmap to your canvas. If you follow the steps below you should get the desired result.

Create a canvas and set its bitmap.

```
mCanvas = new Canvas();
mBitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(scrw, scrh, Config.ARGB_8888);
mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
When you want to erase something you just need to use setXfermode.

public void onClickEraser() 
{ 
   if (isEraserOn)
      mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
   else
      mPaint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

Now you should be able draw with a transparent color using:

```
mCanvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

just save canvas and restore after

```
canvas.saveLayer(clipContainer, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectTopGrey, roundCorners, roundCorners, greyPaint);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectTopGreyClip, roundCorners, roundCorners, clipPaint);
canvas.restore();
```

in this case first rectangle will as destination for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode and the second rectangle as source