# Mask ImageView with round corner background

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, imageview

I am having a `Custom ListView` which contains an `ImageView` and `TextView`. Everything is working fine.

What I want is the image is displayed in list are in round corner. From the Webservice i get the images in rectangle shape. But i want to display it in Round corner `ImageView` as below.

[image]

Can anyone show me the way how can i mask the image in round corner?

I already tried by creating the drawable file as below and applied it as src in `ImageView`. But nothing working for me.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item>
      <shape android:shape="oval" >
         <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
         <padding
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp" />
         <corners android:radius="5dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
      <shape android:shape="oval" >
         <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />
         <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
      </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

**EDITED:**

[image]

I have Applied below solution:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/imagemaskframe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/op_ivpic"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_mask_op"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/imgmask" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate.. This is about masking the image, not about changing the image programatically.

Comment: @GrlsHu how could u resolved that problem will u please help regarding this

Comment: @AliAshiq I have marked answer correct which helped to resolve my problem.

Comment: @GrIsHu which solution u have followed, i am also need same an image in circle will u please help me for this

Comment: Check out in my question. Also you can follow Abhishek Pandey's solution.

Comment: Man u saved my time....ur "layer-list" works perfectly for me... Thanks

Comment: @GrIsHu Hey. Where are you?

Comment: An answer below says that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234152/4291272) helped them. I am preserving it here in case the below answer is deleted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest you to use another method:

One `FrameLayout` and two `ImageView` can do it.

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView />  your image 
    <ImageView />  put a image which has a transparent circle in it
</FrameLayout>
```

then your image can been seen via transparent circle.

Comment: This will make the image block out a square area of whatever's behind it still, correct?

Comment: bad solution, if You want the transparency behind the blocked area

Comment: The order is not correct. In Android the later the code, the closer to  the user the view is. Order should be just the inverse. Great solution!

Comment: This is a very intelligent solution. Thanks for it.

Comment: I still can see the full rectangular image. Below is how my code-

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ic_img_upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="selectPhoto">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_avatar_s2"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_img_upload" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_avatar_mask"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

Comment: try elevating the view if it is'nt visible yet by app:elevation:"10dp",

Answer (score 33):

The best way is to do it in `Canvas` using `PorterDuff` operations and/or `Shaders`. Let's say your `Bitmap` is available and stored in `mBitmap`.

Option 1: Using Shaders.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Load the bitmap as a shader to the paint.
    final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    final Shader shader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    // Draw a circle with the required radius.
    final float halfWidth = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    final float halfHeight = canvas.getHeight()/2;
    final float radius = Math.max(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    canvas.drawCircle(halfWidth, halfHeight, radius, paint);
}
```

Option 2: Using PorterDuff mode.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Create a circular path.
    final float halfWidth = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    final float halfHeight = canvas.getHeight()/2;
    final float radius = Math.max(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    final Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(halfWidth, halfHeight, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);

    final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Note:

1. It's not good to create objects inside onDraw() calls. Hence you should have your paint and shader initially somewhere else. This could probably be done when you set the image bitmap to the view.
2. `Canvas` might need to be saved and restored when it is not backed by a hardware texture. The general ideas around it are not mentioned here.
3. Remember to add `setWillNotDraw(false);` to the constructor.

Additional References:

1. https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/shaders/ has information on `Shaders`.
2. http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/base/ShapedButton.java uses `Path` to curved button in Firefox for Android.
3. http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/constructing-squishy-buttons/ has information on `Canvas` saving, restoring and special cases for pre-ICS.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot! :) only setting the XferMode has to be paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

Comment: option 1 doesn't work well, and I think it should be canvas.drawCircle(halfWidth, halfHeight, radius, >>paint<<);

Comment: option 2 fits perfectly and the additional references are very useful thx

Comment: Option 2 works fine for me but it has dark background. Any idea how to fix it? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24054326/513413

Comment: @Hesam, additional reference #3 resolves the issue with the dark background.

Comment: Check out my answer for a simple ExampleImageView you can just copy/paste to get started

Comment: If I don't add setWillNotDraw(false) everything works, can you explain?

Comment: @Hesam another solution: add `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);` in your custom view's constructor. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387814/drawing-on-canvas-porterduff-mode-clear-draws-black-why

Answer (score 21):

I'd definite recommend Picasso, as others have. This bit of code for one of my Activity classes did the trick for me. It utilized a color I had defined in color.xml and a simple layout (shown below).

```
       ImageView profile_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
       mContext = profile_image.getContext();

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------
        // apply rounding to image
        // see: https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------
        Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
                .borderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_special_orange))
                .borderWidthDp(5)
                .cornerRadiusDp(50)
                .oval(false)
                .build();

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load("http://{some_url}.jpg")
                .fit()
                .transform(transformation)
                .into(profile_image);
```

And the corresponding Layout file:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="12dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="First-Name"
                android:id="@+id/profile_first_name"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Lastname"
                android:id="@+id/profile_last_name" />
        </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: @DavidGeller Hey may I know if it works in this way? I got an icon in white color and I want to put it on top of a circle. So basically it should set the background of the circle rather than set the border

Answer (score 16):

A [`RoundedBitmapDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html) from the [v4 Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4) can be applied to an `ImageView` to achieve the desired effect:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap avatar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar);
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), avatar);
roundDrawable.setCircular(true);
imageView.setImageDrawable(roundDrawable);
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution and **without a black background**!

```
public class CircleImageView extends ImageView
{
    public CircleImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // Create a circular path.
        final float halfWidth = canvas.getWidth()/2;
        final float halfHeight = canvas.getHeight()/2;
        final float radius = Math.max(halfWidth, halfHeight);
        final Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(halfWidth, halfHeight, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);

        canvas.clipPath(path);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: `clipPath` does not work if hardware acceleration is on.

Answer (score 3):

Refer the following code, that exactly do what u want.

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

As you said if you dont want custom view then try the following idea

create 9 patch .png image (like photo frame) with rounded corner and transparent background

then create Relative layout / FrameLayout with two image views as like follows

```
<RelativeLayout ....>
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/myImage" ..>
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/myRoundCorner" android:src="@drawable/myRoundCornerdFrame">
</RelativeLayout>
```

make sure that both the image views having same attributes except image source, and also make sure that image view which has source as myRoundCornerFrame should be over(top) the another image view.

Comment: I don't want to use custom views for this. I want to do this without using any custom library.

Answer (score 2):

Just try [android-shape-imageview](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) - it should helps you.

Answer (score 2):

For those already using Glide, you can achieve the effect with [RequestOptions](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#requestoptions):

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions = requestOptions.transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(radiusInPixels));
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .apply(requestOptions)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())  if you are using glide 4

Answer (score 0):

make a xml file with name roundimage.xml in drawable hdpi folder and try the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
       <corners android:bottomRightRadius="50dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="50dip"  
        android:topRightRadius="50dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="50dip"/>
   </shape>
```

then include the file to your image background as

```
android:background="@drawable/roundimage"
```

I request you to change the dimensions and colors as per your requirements.

please use this code

```
package com.company.app.utils;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;

public class ImageHelper {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

use this as this works.

if you want square cornered then use this

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Context context, Bitmap input, int pixels ,

int w , int h , boolean squareTL, boolean squareTR, boolean squareBL, boolean squareBR)
{

Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

final int color = 0xff424242;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

//make sure that our rounded corner is scaled appropriately
final float roundPx = pixels*densityMultiplier;

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);


//draw rectangles over the corners we want to be square
if (squareTL ){
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w/2, h/2, paint);
}
if (squareTR ){
    canvas.drawRect(w/2, 0, w, h/2, paint);
}
if (squareBL ){
    canvas.drawRect(0, h/2, w/2, h, paint);
}
if (squareBR ){
    canvas.drawRect(w/2, h/2, w, h, paint);
}

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(input, 0,0, paint);

return output;
}
```

Also, I overrode ImageView to put this in so I could define it in xml. You may want to add in some of the logic that the super call makes here, but I've commented it as it's not helpful in my case.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//super.onDraw(canvas);
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();


    Bitmap roundBitmap=CropImageView.getRoundedCornerBitmap( getContext(), 
    bitmap,10, w, h , true, false,true, false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0 , null);
}
```

Comment: I already tried like this but still the images displays in rectangle form. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

here what I did ..but my bg img was rectangle .

```
        ImageView ivLogo;
        ivLogo=(ImageView)fragment.mRoot.findViewById(R.id.iv_offer_logo);
```

then while setting the image ,

```
      if(response.result.Partner.logo_url != null &&                 !response.result.Partner.logo_url.equals("")){
                 ivLogo.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
               DisplayImageOptions options =
                 WWFunctions.getDisplayImage(0);
            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mOfferDetailsFragment.getActivity() ));
          imageLoader.displayImage(response.result.Partner.logo_url, ivLogo, options);
        }
```

Comment: Which API have you used ? What is `DisplayImageOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on sriramramani's answer (including the fix for black background), here is my simple ImageView in its entirety:

```
public class ExampleImageView extends ImageView {
  public ExampleImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
  }

  public ExampleImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    init();
  }

  public ExampleImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    init();
  }

  void init() {
    setWillNotDraw(false);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int count = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null,
            Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG |
                    Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG |
                    Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG |
                    Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG |
                    Canvas.CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Create a circular path.
    final float halfWidth = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    final float halfHeight = canvas.getHeight()/2;
    final float radius = Math.max(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    final Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(halfWidth, halfHeight, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);

    final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    canvas.restoreToCount(count);
  }
}
```

One thing- if I remove this line:

```
setWillNotDraw(false);
```

Everything still works. Not sure if it is needed?