# Android Rounded Corner for Button not working

Tags: android, image, button, imagebutton

I am trying to create a ImageButton for my user portrait.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/new_question_user_portrait"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oler_login_submit_button_bg"
    android:src="@drawable/oler_portrait"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

This is the background xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

My src image is 200*200 px. Round Corner still not working for these code.

Could anyone show me the correct way to create a rounded Image Button with fixed height and width regardless of image source?

Comment: Could you post an image of how it looks?

Comment: Shape = roundrectangle was it. Or not?

Comment: Wow. Such missing image, please post. Very thanks. Many Android.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting the background drawable to work as a mask, which it does not. The drawable is drawn behind the bitmap (after all, it's a background), so it's invisible.

What you are looking for is a mask, have a look at this question and its answers: [Mask ImageView with round corner background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527467/mask-imageview-with-round-corner-background)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  In addition, how could I fix a Image button size regardless of the size of source image? Is it possible to auto zoom in and zoom or to fit the button size?