# Make Image view rounded (not the image)

Tags: android, android-imageview

Requirement is to:

Req 1 : Fetch images from url

R2: save them in cache

R3: make ImageView rounded not the image

So for R1 & R2 I found a library:
http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/

For R3 I've done a lot of R&D , & everything I found converts the image not the ImageView. This is what I've searched:

[Mask ImageView with round corner background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527467/mask-imageview-with-round-corner-background)

[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

I know it's possible to use the ImageView bitmap & get the image rounded but with the specific library I want to use that isn't possible(maybe possible with very complex threading).

So please help me to get the ImageView rounded not the image.

Comment: whats the difference between round imageview and round image ?

Comment: Round ImageView means to actually make the ImageView widget round & round image means to make the jpg or png round

Answer (score 3):

so this is the minimalistic version:

```
class RoundImageView extends ImageView {
    private static final int RADIUS = 32;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mSrcIn;
    private RectF mRect;

    public RoundImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
//        setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        mSrcIn = new Paint();
        mSrcIn.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mRect = new RectF();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable dr = getDrawable();
        if (dr != null) {
            mRect.set(dr.getBounds());
            getImageMatrix().mapRect(mRect);
            mRect.offset(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());

            int rtc = canvas.saveLayer(mRect, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
            // draw DST
            canvas.drawRoundRect(mRect, RADIUS, RADIUS, mPaint);

            canvas.saveLayer(mRect, mSrcIn, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
            // draw SRC
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(rtc);
        }
    }
}
```

or use even shorter one when hardware acceleration is not used and you can use Canvas.clipPath:

```
class RoundImageViewClipped extends ImageView {
    private static final int RADIUS = 32;
    private RectF mRect;
    private Path mClip;

    public RoundImageViewClipped(Context context) {
        super(context);
//        setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        mRect = new RectF();
        mClip = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable dr = getDrawable();
        if (dr != null) {
            mRect.set(dr.getBounds());
            getImageMatrix().mapRect(mRect);
            mRect.offset(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());
            mClip.reset();
            mClip.addRoundRect(mRect, RADIUS, RADIUS, Direction.CCW);

            canvas.clipPath(mClip);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using ImageView. I'm using SmartImageView from the external library I've mentioned. So this didn't work out.

Comment: what didnt help? what did you try?

Comment: I'm using SmartImageView from the external library not ImageView. So I tried to create a class like : class RoundImageViewClipped extends SmartImageView, but that as expected gives ClassCastException.

Comment: where is that ClassCastException ?

Comment: RoundImageView temp = (RoundImageView) findViewById(R.id.smartImageView);

Comment: either use RoundImageView or RoundImageViewClupped, they are two different classes so you cannot cast one to another, or just cast to SmartImageView

Comment: so you have bad luck since for me it works like a charm

Comment: I presume I can get this to work with ImageView. But its just not happening with SmartImageView

Comment: it is just working fine with SmartImageView, otherwise i would not post the answer

Comment: I think I'm not understanding your solution. Can you tell me how to use these classes after : SmartImageView temp = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.smartImageView);

Comment: @PranavMahajan this works but you have to do some specific thinks... i answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22881992/1847899  with the full code..

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't "make the ImageView round," since all Views are actually rectangular, so what you're going to have to do is fake it.

Use a method like this to cut a circle from the image:

```
public Bitmap getRoundedBitmap(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    int targetRadius = scaleBitmapImage.getWidth();
    if(targetRadius > scaleBitmapImage.getHeight()) targetRadius = scaleBitmapImage.getHeight();

    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetRadius, targetRadius, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) scaleBitmapImage.getWidth() - 1) / 2, ((float) scaleBitmapImage.getHeight() - 1) / 2, (Math.min(((float) scaleBitmapImage.getWidth()), ((float) scaleBitmapImage.getHeight())) / 2), Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, scaleBitmapImage.getWidth(), scaleBitmapImage.getHeight()), null);

    return targetBitmap;
}
```

Since the clipped part is transparent, it will appear as if the actual View is a circle. Also make sure that the bounds of the View are squared (or that adjustViewBounds="true") else you may get visual distortions in terms of width or height.

Pretty sure that's as close to a "rounded View" as you can actually get.

Comment: Uhhh. I'm not able to get the bitmap with SmartImageView. I know it can be done with some tricky threading. Can you please look into it.

Comment: What do you mean you're not able to get the Bitmap?

Comment: I know image.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); can be used to get the bitmap, but since the images are being fetched in some different thread I don't have control over, bitmap is always retrieved as null & ultimately gives me NPE.

Comment: That's really not a good way to do it, and I'd be more surprised if you didn't get NPE's doing that. You should look into a lazy-loader solution and get the bitmaps from their references in your app's memory; not from the View you're trying to change...

Answer (score 1):

How about the solution give by [Romain Guy to use a custom Drawable](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/). You're ImageView will not be round and your source image will be untouched.

```
class StreamDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final float mCornerRadius;
    private final RectF mRect = new RectF();
    private final BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final int mMargin;

    StreamDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, float cornerRadius, int margin) {
        mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mMargin = margin;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRect.set(mMargin, mMargin, bounds.width() - mMargin, bounds.height() - mMargin);


    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }       
}
```

Comment: In the StreamDrawable constructor I have to provide the bitmap for the image which is not possible because of the SmartImageView library I'm using(maybe possible with very complex threading)

Answer (score 0):

You can add rounded corners in a android view with the GradientDrawable.
So ,

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
gd.setCornerRadius(15f);
gd.setStroke(1f,Color.BLACK);
yourImageView.setBackground(gd);
```

Comment: yourImageView.setBackground(gd); requires min API level 16 i.e. ver 4.1. That will seriously reduce my app's usability.

Comment: And this method is still showing rectangular images, not circular.

Answer (score 0):

SmartImageView extends from ImageView .. so you just have to extend from SmartImageView

Here is a working solution (based on pskink code & smartImageView lib )

Create a new Class

```
public class RoundedCornersSmartImageView extends SmartImageView{

private int RADIUS = 0;
private RectF mRect;
private Path mClip;

public RoundedCornersSmartImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public RoundedCornersSmartImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public RoundedCornersSmartImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Drawable dr = getDrawable();
    if (dr != null) {
        mRect.set(dr.getBounds());
        getImageMatrix().mapRect(mRect);
        mRect.offset(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());
        mClip.reset();
        mClip.addRoundRect(mRect, RADIUS, RADIUS, Path.Direction.CCW);

        canvas.clipPath(mClip);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}

public void setRadius(int radius){
    this.RADIUS = radius;
}

private void init(){
    mRect = new RectF();
    mClip = new Path();
}
}
```

### USAGE

in your layout file your SmartimageView should look like this

```
<your.package.path.RoundedCornersSmartImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_anonyme_thumb"/>
```

..and init the view in your code this way

```
RoundedCornersSmartImageView thumb_image=(RoundedCornersSmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.list_image);

thumb_image.setRadius(4);
//SmartImageView methode 
thumb_image.setImageUrl(bla.MY_THUMB_URL));
```

Edit your radius for a round image ..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Sadly it didn't work out. I think the issue is because thumb_image.setImageUrl(); takes some time to fetch from the web. Somehow we have to use setradius(4); after the setImageUrl(); has been executed completely.

Comment: did it work for you??
If yes, then remove android:src from your code & then make it work

Comment: first set radius to 32! .. then load the image.. with thumb_image.setImageUrl(...)  .. i will try it for you with a big image ...

Comment: I'm setting the radius first