# How to convert ImageView into Rounded Shape?

Tags: android

I am using following code for converting ImageView into rounded iage, but gettin error at "Mode.SRC_IN" .  Need help. Thank you in advance.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: What error did you get at **Mode.SRC_IN**?

Comment: Check imports, i think you need to import `import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;` instead of `import android.graphics.AvoidXfermode.Mode;`
.

Comment: @user3387867 see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200614/make-image-view-rounded-not-the-image/22207086#22207086

Comment: @pskink i have given the same answer but somebody gave -1 to my answer.

Comment: @KishanDhamat what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this class:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
private Paint objPaint = new Paint();

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
    Log.i("TAG", "Bitmap Width:" + w);

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    objPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    objPaint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, objPaint);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
            sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

}

now in xml file:

```
       <path to your class
        android:id="@+id/iv_leaderboard_profile_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/lederboard_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/lederboard_image_size"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

here

```
  path= com.example.view.RoundedImageView
```

something like that.

hope you understand, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Romain guy has an excellent blog post about achieving rounded corners on ImageViews [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/)

Answer (score 0):

For PorterDuffXfermode, you have to write import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;

For Config.ARGB_8888, you have to write import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;

Otherwise Direct press CTRL + SHIFT + O to organize imports.

Answer (score 0):

A new class is introduced in `android.support.v4`. Which provides you the circled image which any customization.

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(mContext.getResources(), bitmap);
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(pixels);
imageView.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
```

I would recommend to make use of it.