# Why background of Round imageView is dark?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have created a round imageView based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18527882/513413).
It makes image round perfectly. However, I have two problems.

- Image rotated 90 degree that I have no idea why (user clicks on a button, user's gallery displays, user selects an image as his profile pic)
- image has dark background that I have no idea comes from where.

The class that I'm using:

```
public class RoundImageView extends ImageView {

    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;
    private PorterDuffXfermode porterDuffXfermode;

    public RoundImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public RoundImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RoundImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        path = new Path();
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        porterDuffXfermode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // Create a circular path.
        final float halfWidth = canvas.getWidth()/2;
        final float halfHeight = canvas.getHeight()/2;
        final float radius = Math.max(halfWidth, halfHeight);

        path.addCircle(halfWidth, halfHeight, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);

        paint.setXfermode(porterDuffXfermode);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

The way I'm adding it in layout:

```
<com.allstarxi.widget.RoundImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_description"
                    android:scaleType="center" />
```

This is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hesam , I get your code and put    mTopCard.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
inside init() method and works for me, I also have hardware acceleration flag "true" on manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, I couldn't find how to fix this issue, I used [RoundedImageView library](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView). It is good when you fix width and height of imageView.
This is my sample:

```
<com.makeramen.RoundedImageView
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:id="@+id/ivUserPic"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_description"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:mutate_background="true"
                    app:border_width="0dp"
                    app:corner_radius="18dp"
                    app:oval="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting this in the RoundImageView class :

```
    public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    //Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 60, 60, false);
    //return _bmp;
    return output;
}
```

Then put this in onDraw:

```
getCroppedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getDrawable()));
```

Comment: Thanks, Just one thing. BitmapFactory.decodeResource() is looking getResources as first parameter which is correct and 'int' as second parameter which is drawable. Should I pass something else instead of getDrawable()?

Comment: If the image is always the same, then try R.drawable.image_id. Otherwise, try making the image into a Bitmap another way and pass it into getCroppedImage

Comment: I used this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/8306683/513413 (to get bitmap of image). Image displays but it is in square shape rather than Circle. I'm trying to find what is the problem. Your code seems okay!

Answer (score 0):

I have same experienced before because I loaded something from database in UI Thread, Are you load something from database/disk in UI Thread? if yes you need to load it using AsynTask, if not it will effecting your UI Rendering process

Answer (score -1):

It is all about this: `android:scaleType="center"`

Try another scaleTypes from here and see the result:

CENTER, 
CENTER_CROP,
CENTER_INSIDE ,
FIT_CENTER ,
FIT_END ,
FIT_START,
FIT_XY,
MATRIX