# Loading bitmap with too large height in android ImageView

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, android-bitmap, universal-image-loader

I am stuck with a weird issue with bitmap, I have some images saved locally in my app with too large height and i am showing the images in a `imageview` which support zoom and pan. what i am doing is i am getting the bitmap of the image using universal image loader and then loading that bitmap in a `imageview`. Now if i am showing the bitmap as it is without scaling the image using :

```
DisplayImageOptions opts = new 
DisplayImageOptions.Builder().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE).build();
bitmap = ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync(uri.toString(), opts);
```

then nothing is showing in a `imageview` but i am getting the error in `logcat` :

> W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
>   (686x7628, max=4096x4096)

and if i am trying to load the image with scaling then quality of image gets destroyed as image contain text only it is not readable.

**ScreenShot from device :**

[image]

**Original Image :**

[image]

Size of Image is 1.2Mb only i don't know how to handle this as all the libraries i tried reducing the quality of image to non readable formate and if i am trying to load image bitmap directly to `imageview` it is not showing. Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: This is quite large image in pixels . Try to load it `HttpUrlConnection` once and MOdify the `ImageView` . [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273390/android-how-to-place-a-scrollable-photo-into-imageview) . There are also some libraries available to load high resolution Bitmaps .You can also use `WebView` to load this image.

Comment: Benefit with `WebView` is it will cache it automatically .And it provide auto Scroll .

Comment: @ADM i am using `imageview ` which supports Zoom and Pan, using `webview` will have bad user experience i think

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum supported dimension for a device using

```
 val canvas = Canvas()
    canvas.getMaximumBitmapHeight()
    canvas.getMaximumBitmapWidth()
```

**As per the doc**

For height

```
/**
 * Returns the maximum allowed height for bitmaps drawn with this canvas.
 * Attempting to draw with a bitmap taller than this value will result
 * in an error.
 *
 * @see #getMaximumBitmapWidth()
 */
public int getMaximumBitmapHeight() {
    return MAXMIMUM_BITMAP_SIZE;
}
```

For width

```
 /**
 * Returns the maximum allowed width for bitmaps drawn with this canvas.
 * Attempting to draw with a bitmap wider than this value will result
 * in an error.
 *
 * @see #getMaximumBitmapHeight()
 */
public int getMaximumBitmapWidth() {
    return MAXMIMUM_BITMAP_SIZE;
}
```

So while setting the `Bitmap` you should consider these dimensions and set the Bitmap accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think image-loading libraries won't help you with such images. Library should scale original image for size less max texture size. So those long images are vastly scaled resulting non-readable text. In your case you should handle image loading yourself: fetch image and draw it on canvas, maybe by parts or somehow.

Anyway, loading text as image of those size looks like not very great idea :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you please share some idea or any helpful link how to fetch image and draw it on canvas. I tried but found no success till today.