# How can I implement the custom view similar to this image?

Tags: android

I want to implement this seek bar in my app. I have created a custom view for the same. The only problem I am facing is how to change the color of the text from black to white when the circular view goes over the text. [The image showing the custom view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrB90.png)

My onDraw method()

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    canvas?.save()
    canvas?.drawCircle(thumbX + 20F, thumbY, thumbRadius, mThumbPaint)
    canvas?.drawBitmap(drawTextBitmap(), 0F, 0F, Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
    })
}
```

drawTextBitmap method which draws the track of 1 2 3 4 5 .....

```
private fun drawTextBitmap(): Bitmap {
    val h = height
    val w = width

    val conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf)
    val newCanvas: Canvas? = Canvas(bmp)
    //newCanvas?.drawColor(Color.GREEN)

    val initialOffsetX = paddingLeftCustom + thumbRadius
    //newCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
    for (i in 1..10) {
        val textPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG or Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
        textPaint.color = Color.BLACK
        textPaint.textSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
            20f,
            resources.displayMetrics
        )
            .toInt().toFloat()
        textPaint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT
        val metric: Paint.FontMetrics = textPaint.fontMetrics
        val textHeight = Math.ceil((metric.descent - metric.ascent).toDouble()).toInt()
        textPaint.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.DST)
        val y = (textHeight - metric.descent) as Float
        newCanvas?.drawText(i.toString(), initialOffsetX + (i - 1) * spaceBetweenTexts, y, textPaint)
    }

    return bmp
}
```

I am using Porter's Duff Concept. The issue I am facing is I want to blend the text color and the thumb color (Circular View) but on whichever view I apply my color filter to it takes the canvas color into consideration.

Comment: You gotta share some code to this custom view.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a  for that text color.
Something like:
**seat_item_text_color_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@color/black">
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:color="@color/white">
    </item>
</selector>
```

You will set this selector as text color for that TextView.

Comment: I cant use it I think. Because what I am doing here is 
1. Creating a custom view
2. In the custom view canvas I am creating a bitmap in this bitmap using the drawTextBitmap function that I have above mentioned I have drawn text using canvas.drawText function.
3.  Then I have created a thumb or a circular view.
So how can I use a selector on a custom drawn Text

Comment: In that case you will need to add a state in your custom view (pressed & default) and based on that state to set the color of the TextPaint. Do not forget to force the redraw when the state changes.

Comment: I have found the way the only problem now I have is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387814/drawing-on-canvas-porterduff-mode-clear-draws-black-why
But nothing seems to work in my case.