mDrawPaint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT) is not working
I've created custom drawing view class as per my requirement , in which there is something wrong with eraser whenever I use it every time it draws black lines instead of erasing drawn lines, Here are some snippets from my drawing view class :
drawPaint variable

private var mDrawPaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        color = currentColor
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG)
    }

onTouch Event

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)

        val touchX = event.x
        val touchY = event.y

        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                // First, check if the remove button itself is pressed
                val shapeWithRemoveButtonPressed = shapes.find { shape ->
                    val removeButtonBounds = getRemoveButtonBounds(shape)
                    removeButtonBounds.contains(touchX, touchY)
                }

                if (shapeWithRemoveButtonPressed != null) {
                    shapes.remove(shapeWithRemoveButtonPressed)
                    invalidate()
                    return false
                }

                // Check if the touch is within any bitmap
                for ((index, pair) in bitmaps.withIndex().reversed()) {
                    val (bitmap, position) = pair
                    val deleteButtonX = position.x + bitmap.width - deleteButtonSize
                    val deleteButtonY = position.y

                    if (touchX >= deleteButtonX && touchX <= deleteButtonX + deleteButtonSize &&
                        touchY >= deleteButtonY && touchY <= deleteButtonY + deleteButtonSize
                    ) {
                        removeBitmap(index) // Remove the bitmap if the delete button is tapped
                        return false
                    }
                    if (touchX >= position.x && touchX <= position.x + bitmap.width &&
                        touchY >= position.y && touchY <= position.y + bitmap.height
                    ) {
                        // Calculate the offset between the touch point and the bitmap's top-left corner
                        touchOffset.x = touchX - position.x
                        touchOffset.y = touchY - position.y
                        selectedBitmapIndex = index
                        selectedBitmap = pair.first
                        isDragging = true// Select this bitmap for dragging
                        break
                    }
                }

                // If no remove button was pressed, check if a shape was selected
                val shape = getShapeAt(touchX, touchY)
                if (shape != null) {
                    selectedShape = shape
                    lastTouchX = touchX
                    lastTouchY = touchY
                    isDragging = true
                    return true
                }

                // Handle drawing/eraser mode
                mDrawPath!!.color = color
                mDrawPath!!.brushThickness = mBrushSize
                mDrawPath!!.reset()
                mDrawPath!!.moveTo(touchX, touchY)
                if (isEraserActive) {
                    eraserX = touchX
                    eraserY = touchY
                    eraseShapesUnderEraser()
                    invalidate()
                    return true

                }
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (isDragging && (selectedShape != null || selectedBitmap != null)) {
                    val dx = event.x - lastTouchX
                    val dy = event.y - lastTouchY
                    if (selectedShape != null) {
                        selectedShape!!.x += dx
                        selectedShape!!.y += dy
                    }
                    lastTouchX = event.x
                    lastTouchY = event.y
                    invalidate()
                    // If a bitmap is selected, update its position based on the touch movement
                    selectedBitmapIndex?.let { index ->
                        val (bitmap, position) = bitmaps[index]
                        position.x = event.x - touchOffset.x
                        position.y = event.y - touchOffset.y
                        invalidate() // Redraw the canvas with the updated position
                    }
                    return true
                }

                mDrawPath!!.lineTo(touchX, touchY)
                if (isEraserActive) {
                    eraserX = touchX
                    eraserY = touchY
                    eraseShapesUnderEraser()
                    invalidate()
                    return true
                }
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                if (!isDragging) {
                    mPaths.add(mDrawPath!!)
                    mDrawPath = CustomPath(color, mBrushSize)
                }
                isDragging = false
                selectedShape = null
                selectedBitmapIndex = null
                mPaths.add(mDrawPath!!)
                mDrawPath = CustomPath(color, mBrushSize)
                mUndoPaths.clear() // Clear redo history after a new drawing
                if (isEraserActive) {
                    eraserX = 0f
                    eraserY = 0f
                    invalidate()
                    return true
                }
            }

            else -> return false
        }
        invalidate()
        return true
    }

eraser method

fun setEraser(eraserSize: Float) {
        this.eraserSize = eraserSize
        mDrawPaint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
        mDrawPaint.strokeWidth = eraserSize
        isEraserActive = true
    }

Following things has been tried :

tried creating separate object of eraser

val eraserPaint = Paint().apply {
        xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 50f  // Adjust to your desired eraser thickness 
}


tried different modes of xfermode

xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT)
xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT)

3.tried setting color of drawpaint to transparent
mDrawPaint.color = Color.TRANSPARENT

None of the things have been working
Help me to fix the issue
Thanks in advance

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387814/drawing-on-canvas-porterduff-mode-clear-draws-black-why
